# Parse.com multiples options for a pointer, array('C00Bdpdpae','4T619487iy','uynOEwwg4a')

Tags: php, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com with the PHP library, I want to do a filter for a ClassA with an pointer to _User class for all users with status 1, but with a wherePointer function I can't use something like:

```
$qry->wherePointer('userId','_User.status','1')
```

Other option, I can try is get first all users with status 1 in an array but I don't know how use a whereContainedIn() with a pointer:

```
$uqry->whereContainedIn('userId',array('C00Bdpdpae','4T619487iy','uynOEwwg4a')) ;
```

I tryed in this form but return a empty array.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, when i did the question I was used a older parse library (for that i used the function whereContaindedIn), now I'm using the new Parse.com SDK for PHP, and i can use the function $uqry->containedIn, the trick is use the the function in this way:

```
$uqry->containedIn('createdBy', array(new parseObject('_User','3YjQkMwfff'),new parseObject('_User','3YjQkMwggg'))) ;
```

Right in array for the condition, i hope works for others.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ContainedIn query as follows:

```
$query->containedIn( 'userId', array('C00Bdpdpae','4T619487iy','uynOEwwg4a') );
```

Comment: thans you @Niraj but my problem was the array of objectIds